# Speed-up ASCIInema by editing file

Tags: json, performance, asciinema

I'm using [ASCIInema](https://asciinema.org/).
And I try to speed it up. `asciinema --speed` solves this problem. But how to set the speed in the `file.cast` itself, so that it could be published and the user can execute `asciinema play` without an additional parameter?

Comment: @zx485, very good edit. thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a simple way: edit file with `jq`:

- in bash

  ```
  cat file.cast | { read; echo "$REPLY"; jq -c '.[0]=.[0]/4'; } > fast.cast
  ```
- in fish

  ```
  cat file.cast | begin read; echo "$REPLY"; jq -c '.[0]=.[0]/4'; end > fast.cast
  ```

`read` stands to read first line which contains json object - short description about this cast, this object should not be passed to `jq`. `jq` processes arrays, zeroth element is timestamp, to speed up payback script divides every timestamp by a specified ratio, here it is `4`.

**example**
`file.cast`

```
{"version": 2, "width": 182, "height": 28, "timestamp": 1566499237, "env": {"SHELL": "/usr/local/bin/fish", "TERM": "xterm-256color"}}
[0.027813, "o", "\u001b]1337;RemoteHost=kyb@kyb-mbo.local\u0007\u001b]1337;CurrentDir=/Users/kyb/devel/git-rev-label\u0007\u001b]1337;ShellIntegrationVersion=6;shell=fish\u0007"]
[0.046757, "o", "\u001b]1337;RemoteHost=kyb@kyb-mbo.local\u0007\u001b]1337;CurrentDir=/Users/kyb/devel/git-rev-label\u0007"]
[0.050038, "o", "\u001b]0;fish /Users/kyb/devel/git-rev-label\u0007\u001b[30m\u001b(B\u001b[m"]
[0.058719, "o", "\u001b[?2004h"]
[0.162696, "o", "\u001b]0;fish /Users/kyb/devel/git-rev-label\u0007\u001b[30m\u001b(B\u001b[m"]
[0.162909, "o", "\u001b[38;5;237m⏎\u001b(B\u001b[m                                                                                                                                                                                     \r⏎ \r\u001b[K"]
[0.164234, "o", "\u001b]133;D;0\u0007\u001b]133;A\u0007\u001b[44m\u001b[30m ~/d/git-rev-label \u001b[42m\u001b[34m \u001b[42m\u001b[30m➦ d0e4dc8   \u001b[30m\u001b(B\u001b[m\u001b[32m \u001b[30m\u001b(B\u001b[m\u001b]133;B\u0007\u001b[K"]
[2.316447, "o", "g"]
[2.316686, "o", "\b\u001b[38;5;167mg\u001b[30m\u001b(B\u001b[m"]
[2.318507, "o", "\u001b[38;5;246mit rev-label\u001b[12D\u001b[30m\u001b(B\u001b[m"]
[2.43537, "o", "\u001b[38;5;167mi\u001b[38;5;246mt rev-label\u001b[11D\u001b[30m\u001b(B\u001b[m"]
[2.464359, "o", "\u001b[38;5;167mt\u001b[38;5;246m rev-label\u001b[10D\u001b[30m\u001b(B\u001b[m"]
[2.464657, "o", "\b\b\b\u001b[38;5;176mgit\u001b[38;5;246m rev-label\u001b[10D\u001b[30m\u001b(B\u001b[m"]
[2.599488, "o", "\u001b[38;5;176m \u001b[38;5;246mrev-label\u001b[9D\u001b[30m\u001b(B\u001b[m"]
[2.599678, "o", "\b \u001b[38;5;246mrev-label\u001b[9D\u001b[30m\u001b(B\u001b[m"]
[2.737237, "o", "r\u001b[38;5;246mev-label\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\u001b[30m\u001b(B\u001b[m"]
[2.737514, "o", "\b\u001b[38;5;110m\u001b[4mr\u001b[38;5;246m\u001b[24mev-label\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\u001b[30m\u001b(B\u001b[m"]
[2.817482, "o", "\u001b[38;5;110m\u001b[4me\u001b[38;5;246m\u001b[24mv-label\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\u001b[30m\u001b(B\u001b[m"]
[3.033631, "o", "\u001b[38;5;110m\u001b[4mv\u001b[38;5;246m\u001b[24m-label\b\b\b\b\b\b\u001b[30m\u001b(B\u001b[m"]
[3.033812, "o", "\b\b\b\u001b[38;5;110mrev\u001b[38;5;246m-label\b\b\b\b\b\b\u001b[30m\u001b(B\u001b[m"]
[3.951287, "o", "\u001b[38;5;110m-label\u001b[30m\u001b(B\u001b[m"]
[4.581453, "o", "\r\n"]
[4.581681, "o", "\u001b[30m\u001b(B\u001b[m\u001b[?2004l"]
[4.58185, "o", "\u001b]133;C;\u0007"]
[4.582158, "o", "\u001b]0;git /Users/kyb/devel/git-rev-label\u0007\u001b["]
[4.582306, "o", "30m\u001b(B\u001b[m\r"]
[4.689255, "o", "brantozyabra-c136-gd0e4dc8\r\n"]
[4.690204, "o", "\u001b]1337;RemoteHost=kyb@kyb-mbo.local\u0007\u001b]1337;CurrentDir=/Users/kyb/devel/git-rev-label\u0007"]
[4.690383, "o", "\u001b[?2004h"]
[4.772316, "o", "\u001b]0;fish /Users/kyb/devel/git-rev-label\u0007\u001b[30m\u001b(B\u001b[m"]
[4.772502, "o", "\u001b[38;5;237m⏎\u001b(B\u001b[m                                                                                                                                                                                     \r⏎ \r\u001b[K\u001b]133;D;0\u0007\u001b]133;A\u0007\u001b[44m\u001b[30m ~/d/git-rev-label \u001b[42m\u001b[34m \u001b[42m\u001b[30m➦ d0e4dc8   \u001b[30m\u001b(B\u001b[m\u001b[32m \u001b[30m\u001b(B\u001b[m\u001b]133;B\u0007\u001b[K"]
[6.901142, "o", "\r\n\u001b[30m\u001b(B\u001b[m\u001b[30m\u001b(B\u001b[m"]
[6.901321, "o", "\u001b[?2004l"]
```

`fast.cast`

```
{"version": 2, "width": 182, "height": 28, "timestamp": 1566499237, "env": {"SHELL": "/usr/local/bin/fish", "TERM": "xterm-256color"}}
[0.00695325,"o","\u001b]1337;RemoteHost=kyb@kyb-mbo.local\u0007\u001b]1337;CurrentDir=/Users/kyb/devel/git-rev-label\u0007\u001b]1337;ShellIntegrationVersion=6;shell=fish\u0007"]
[0.01168925,"o","\u001b]1337;RemoteHost=kyb@kyb-mbo.local\u0007\u001b]1337;CurrentDir=/Users/kyb/devel/git-rev-label\u0007"]
[0.0125095,"o","\u001b]0;fish /Users/kyb/devel/git-rev-label\u0007\u001b[30m\u001b(B\u001b[m"]
[0.01467975,"o","\u001b[?2004h"]
[0.040674,"o","\u001b]0;fish /Users/kyb/devel/git-rev-label\u0007\u001b[30m\u001b(B\u001b[m"]
[0.04072725,"o","\u001b[38;5;237m⏎\u001b(B\u001b[m                                                                                                                                                                                     \r⏎ \r\u001b[K"]
[0.0410585,"o","\u001b]133;D;0\u0007\u001b]133;A\u0007\u001b[44m\u001b[30m ~/d/git-rev-label \u001b[42m\u001b[34m \u001b[42m\u001b[30m➦ d0e4dc8   \u001b[30m\u001b(B\u001b[m\u001b[32m \u001b[30m\u001b(B\u001b[m\u001b]133;B\u0007\u001b[K"]
[0.57911175,"o","g"]
[0.5791715,"o","\b\u001b[38;5;167mg\u001b[30m\u001b(B\u001b[m"]
[0.57962675,"o","\u001b[38;5;246mit rev-label\u001b[12D\u001b[30m\u001b(B\u001b[m"]
[0.6088425,"o","\u001b[38;5;167mi\u001b[38;5;246mt rev-label\u001b[11D\u001b[30m\u001b(B\u001b[m"]
[0.61608975,"o","\u001b[38;5;167mt\u001b[38;5;246m rev-label\u001b[10D\u001b[30m\u001b(B\u001b[m"]
[0.61616425,"o","\b\b\b\u001b[38;5;176mgit\u001b[38;5;246m rev-label\u001b[10D\u001b[30m\u001b(B\u001b[m"]
[0.649872,"o","\u001b[38;5;176m \u001b[38;5;246mrev-label\u001b[9D\u001b[30m\u001b(B\u001b[m"]
[0.6499195,"o","\b \u001b[38;5;246mrev-label\u001b[9D\u001b[30m\u001b(B\u001b[m"]
[0.68430925,"o","r\u001b[38;5;246mev-label\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\u001b[30m\u001b(B\u001b[m"]
[0.6843785,"o","\b\u001b[38;5;110m\u001b[4mr\u001b[38;5;246m\u001b[24mev-label\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\u001b[30m\u001b(B\u001b[m"]
[0.7043705,"o","\u001b[38;5;110m\u001b[4me\u001b[38;5;246m\u001b[24mv-label\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\u001b[30m\u001b(B\u001b[m"]
[0.75840775,"o","\u001b[38;5;110m\u001b[4mv\u001b[38;5;246m\u001b[24m-label\b\b\b\b\b\b\u001b[30m\u001b(B\u001b[m"]
[0.758453,"o","\b\b\b\u001b[38;5;110mrev\u001b[38;5;246m-label\b\b\b\b\b\b\u001b[30m\u001b(B\u001b[m"]
[0.98782175,"o","\u001b[38;5;110m-label\u001b[30m\u001b(B\u001b[m"]
[1.14536325,"o","\r\n"]
[1.14542025,"o","\u001b[30m\u001b(B\u001b[m\u001b[?2004l"]
[1.1454625,"o","\u001b]133;C;\u0007"]
[1.1455395,"o","\u001b]0;git /Users/kyb/devel/git-rev-label\u0007\u001b["]
[1.1455765,"o","30m\u001b(B\u001b[m\r"]
[1.17231375,"o","brantozyabra-c136-gd0e4dc8\r\n"]
[1.172551,"o","\u001b]1337;RemoteHost=kyb@kyb-mbo.local\u0007\u001b]1337;CurrentDir=/Users/kyb/devel/git-rev-label\u0007"]
[1.17259575,"o","\u001b[?2004h"]
[1.193079,"o","\u001b]0;fish /Users/kyb/devel/git-rev-label\u0007\u001b[30m\u001b(B\u001b[m"]
[1.1931255,"o","\u001b[38;5;237m⏎\u001b(B\u001b[m                                                                                                                                                                                     \r⏎ \r\u001b[K\u001b]133;D;0\u0007\u001b]133;A\u0007\u001b[44m\u001b[30m ~/d/git-rev-label \u001b[42m\u001b[34m \u001b[42m\u001b[30m➦ d0e4dc8   \u001b[30m\u001b(B\u001b[m\u001b[32m \u001b[30m\u001b(B\u001b[m\u001b]133;B\u0007\u001b[K"]
[1.7252855,"o","\r\n\u001b[30m\u001b(B\u001b[m\u001b[30m\u001b(B\u001b[m"]
[1.72533025,"o","\u001b[?2004l"]
```

Comment: `jq -sc '.[0], (.[1:][] | .[0]/=4)' file.cast > fast.cast` Nice to do all within jq, but took a bit of mucking about, so not sure it's really "better". BTW compacts the first line.

Comment: Could you please add some more description about how does this work.

Comment: Make the lines into an array, then break down the array. `-s` slurps in lines as if they were an array. `.[0]` is then the first line, and `.[1:]` is an array of all the other lines. `[]` gives us each element in that array (i.e. the rest of the lines). `\=` is division operation and assign, like `+=` etc in C. `,` means that both sides get the same input (the whole array). Parentheses are because `,` binds tighter than `|`, and we want the `\=4` to only apply to the rest of the lines. I like jq but always find it confusing to use.

Answer (score 15):

To make the speed change persistent you need to adjust the timing of each event in the cast file.

jq based solution proposed by @kyb is one way. Another is to re-record the cast with this command:

```
asciinema rec -c 'asciinema play -s 4 file.cast' faster-file.cast
```

This will create a new recording, but instead of recording a new interactive shell it will record the sped up playback of the old cast.

You don't need jq for this, however the downside is that **it's not instant** - it takes as much time as the playback at a desired speed.

Answer (score 4):

The tool [asciinema-edit](https://github.com/cirocosta/asciinema-edit) seems to do just that (among other post-processing of asciinema recordings). From the README:

```
EXAMPLES:
   Make the whole cast ("123.cast") twice as fast:

     asciinema-edit speed --factor 2 ./123.cast

   Cut the duration in half:

     asciinema-edit speed --factor 0.5 ./123.cast
```